# Overriden method not called?

Tags: swift

Class B is subclass of class A `(B : A)`

I initialise the class as `B.init()`

When invoked in A, the overriden `method(`) is never called unless I use the cast:

```
class A {
    ...
    self.method() //A method called
    (self as! B).method() //B method called
}
```

Why?

Since I initialise the instance as B, I expect it's calling the overriden method, but this is not true, unless I use the cast.

Comment: I think there's something going on that's not obvious from what you've posted.  In the simplest case, the B method will be called.

Comment: Duplicate of [Overriding methods in Swift extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions) ([see below comment thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38996783/overriden-method-not-called#comment65346443_38997022))

Comment: Who mentioned anything about extensions ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some mistake behind scenes. I constructed your example and it works as expected:

```
class A {
    func method() {
        print("A")
    }
    func check() {
        method()
        (self as? B)?.method()
    }
}
class B: A {
    override func method() {
        print("B")
    }
}
```

Somewhere else:

```
let b = B()
b.check()
//B
//B
```

Comment: It should also work if `check` simply calls `self.method()`.

Comment: @PhillipMills it work with `self` also, since `self` added implicitly

Comment: I've figured it out. It seems that that the method is not called if it's in an extension of B (it was my case). So, if I add the method in the extension B, instead of in class B, it's not called. Why? It should still override class A method, or not?

Comment: @Patrick declarations in extensions can't override, so that sounds weird.

Comment: @Patrick If your class inherits from `NSObject`, then see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions – otherwise it shouldn't compile as you cannot override methods in extensions.

Comment: @dfri  My class inherits from UIViewController, so NSObject.

Comment: @Harmish Thanks for the link. That's indeed my issue.

Comment: @Patrick that is a non-general Swift case; for future reference, please mention such (relevant) details in your questions. Anyway, with that additional detail, the link provided by Hamish should be a target for dupe marking this thread.

Comment: @dfri I agree, this is a duplicate. Unfortunately it's hard to think about all details: if I had realised those details by myself without help, I would probably not posted the question.

Comment: @Patrick finding a dupe is not the easiest of tasks when pondering over something, but usually someone else can help out (like Hamish, in this case :). Also, sometimes when narrowing down a questoin to a minimal example, one runs the risk of removing a little to many details. Just take with you that many things that seems as peculiar in Swift (w.r.t. language guide/official sources) occur in the interjoining of Swift and Obj-C, e.g. for classes subclassing `NSObject`.

Comment: @dfri I'm not sure I've understood your point here ;) I've read all documentation you mentioned already. I've asked a question in the community, since I could not figure out a solution to my problem. Hamish passed me a link (that I could not find, without a further investigation in my problem thanks to the help from others). Of course, if I had thought all details in advance I would have written them, but I didn't think about them. So that's what a community like Stack Overflow is useful for. Isn't? :)

Comment: @Patrick My previous comment was meant as _"Don't worry, finding existing SO threads that might answer one's question can be hard, as well also asking a perfectly spot-on question with all necessary (but not redundant) details! Just take with you the insight of Obj-C/Swift peculiarities as they pop up a little here and there!"_, and was in no way criticising this question. But maybe the comment was a bit verbose and the _"Don't worry"_ intent was lost! :)