# Preferred status bar style of view controller is ignored when in navigation controller

Tags: ios, uikit

I'm writing an iOS App with multiple views. I've set the App to use ViewController-based status bar style, which allows me to use the following code

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

That worked like expected.

But then I've embedded the views in a navigation controller and connected a BarButtonItem with a showSegue. Since then the ViewController of the view switched to ignores the style settings and shows the default black status bar.

Comment: Can you show your BarButtonItem code and segue code

Comment: There is no code :) I've added the segue via the interface build ('show') and the new ViewController only has the overridden var. Anything else I can help with?

Comment: I've also set the lightContent via the interface builder for the navigation controller as well as for the second view. But still no luck

Answer (score 79, accepted):

When you're in a navigation controller that will not get called.  The navigation controller's preferredStatusBarStyle will be called.  Try this along with your code:

```
extension UINavigationController {

   open override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
      return topViewController?.preferredStatusBarStyle ?? .default
   }
}
```

Comment: Guessed something like that. Got it working by implementing a custom NavigationController Class overriding that var. But your solution is better. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great solution! Don't forget add to info.plist View controller-based status bar appearance = Yes

Comment: The proper way to do it is overriding `childForStatusBarStyle` instead.

Comment: @Codenator81 for Xcode 10+, Swift 4.2 it's YES by default

Comment: The compiler is allowing you to override the extension for compatibility with Objective-C. But it's actually violating the language directive.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274660/1442541

Comment: am i put the code on viewcontroller? or create new file for the extension? because it's not going there in my viewcontroller (debugging)

Answer (score 11):

There is a solution that is a bit more concise (and recommended by Apple):

```
extension UINavigationController {
    override open var childForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return topViewController
    }
}
```

Comment: works great, except it doesn't seem to animate between the two states...

Comment: Thanks, This answer really helps me.