# Change Status Bar style in XCode 8.2 / Swift 3.0 (No "View controller-based status bar appearance")

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

I am trying to modify the appearance of my status bar (make text white/ set the Style to "light"). I managed to set the background color by adding this to my AppDelegate.swift file:

```
let statWindow = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey:"statusBarWindow") as! UIView
let statusBar = statWindow.subviews[0] as UIView
statusBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255.0, green: 0/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

However, when I go to change the style of the text of the status bar, even changing this under General > Deployment Info > Status Bar Style (changing this to "Light") does not work.

I also tried to modify the status bar through Info.plist, but there is no field for "View controller-based status bar appearance" (see second image). Also, there is no option for a "light" style under the Status bar style option (see below image):

Status bar style options:
[image: ScreenShot]

No view controller status bar field:
[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In each UIViewController of your application, you should override `preferredStatusBarStyle` property:

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

and eventually, call:

```
<your controller>.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
```

If this statusBar style is throughout all your application, you should make a `BaseViewController` class that implement this, and make all you view controllers inherit from BaseViewController.

Comment: see also here in addition to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026514/swift-viewcontroller-ignores-status-bar-style

Answer (score 10):

The step you missed is Info.plist.

Open the info.plist file of your app and set the **UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance** to **NO** (as shown below).

[image: Screenshot]

**Note**: This key can be added if not already present by:

1) Hovering over an existing entry to reveal add/remove icons:

[image]

2) Click the plus icon to add a new key/value pair:

[image]

3) Paste `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` into the key field and set it's value to `NO`. Note the key will change to `View controller-based status...` when deselected but it's the same thing:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You missed some details from my post - that field doesn't exist in my info.plist :( I added a second image to show you what my info.plist file looks like

Comment: I believe @enghong is suggesting you add that key to the Info.plist. You can do so by hovering over an existing entry which should reveal a plus/minus icon pair, click the plus icon, paste the suggested key, and set the value to NO (which was the default for me). You should then have white status bar text throughout the application without needing to manually set each UIViewController subclass. At least that's what worked for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer, exactly what I was looking for. With BOTH keys set, the global status bar content is set to light, no code needed.

Answer (score 7):

**swift 3**

if View controller-based status bar appearance = YES in Info.plist

then use this extension for all NavigationController

```
    extension UINavigationController
    {
        override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
         }
     }
```

if there is no UINavigationController and only have UIViewController then use Below code:

```
    extension UIViewController
    {
        override open var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
         }
     }
```

**objective c**

create category class

**For UIViewController**

In UIViewController+StatusBarStyle.h

```
 @interface UIViewController (StatusBarStyle)
 @end
```

In UIViewController+StatusBarStyle.m

```
 #import "UIViewController+StatusBarStyle.h"

 @implementation UIViewController (StatusBarStyle)

 -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
  return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
 }

 @end
```

**For UINavigationController**

In UINavigationController+StatusBarStyle.h

```
 @interface UINavigationController (StatusBarStyle)
 @end
```

In UINavigationController+StatusBarStyle.m

```
 #import "UINavigationController+StatusBarStyle.h"

 @implementation UINavigationController (StatusBarStyle)

 -(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
  return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
 }

 @end
```

Answer (score 0):

For Xcode 10 You can simply create a class for UIViewController or UITableViewController ecc. and put it before your UIViewController class, you can call this class in all view controller is needed a light content status bar...

```
class UIViewControllerWithLightStatusBar: UIViewController {
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
return UIStatusBarStyle.lightContent
}
}
```

in AppDelegate set the status Bar:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = false
    UINavigationBar.appearance().barStyle = .blackOpaque

    return true
}
```

now you change the class UIViewController with UIViewControllerWithLightStatusBar

```
class YourViewController: UIViewControllerWithLightStatusBar {
...
}
```

And that's it...