# preferredStatusBarStyle is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, statusbar

I used to use `setStatusBarStyle` in my project and it works fine, but it is deprecated so I use `preferredStatusBarStyle`, that didn't work. 
knowing that I've:

1. Call the method setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate.
2. Set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to NO in info.plist
3. Override the function

   - (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
     {
     return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
     }

   this function is not called

*Note*: I'm using navigation controller.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38740648/how-to-set-status-bar-style-in-swift-3

Comment: The correct way to set status bar style is to set "View controller-based status bar appearance" to YES and use preferredStatusBarStyle. When using a navigation controller one more step is needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026514/swift-viewcontroller-ignores-status-bar-style

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Here is [Apple Guidelines/Instruction](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/status-bars/) about status bar change.

If you want to set status bar style, application level then set `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `NO` in your `.plist` file. And in your `appdelegate` > `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add following ine (programatically you can do it from app delegate).

**Objective C**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES];
```

**Swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    application.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    return true
}
```

---

if you want to set status bar style, at view controller level then follow these steps:

1. Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the `.plist` file, if you need to set status bar style at UIViewController level only.
2. In the viewDidLoad add function - `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`
3. override preferredStatusBarStyle in your view controller.

**Objective C**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
}

- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
}

override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
    return .lightContent
}
```

Set value of .plist according to status bar style setup level.

[image]

---

You can set background color for status bar during application launch or during viewDidLoad of your view controller.

```
extension UIApplication {

    var statusBarView: UIView? {
        return value(forKey: "statusBar") as? UIView
    }

}

// Set upon application launch, if you've application based status bar
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return true
    }
}


or 
// Set it from your view controller if you've view controller based statusbar
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

}
```

Here is result:

[image]

---

Comment: This is the only thing that works for me and yet it is deprecated.

Comment: It doesn't work if the viewcontroller is wrapped in a UINavigationController

Comment: if your application use navigationController，you should also implement childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle.

Comment: I added my answer here, Please have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56801660/299610