# preferredStatusBarStyle .lightContent doesn't work with Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, statusbar, uistatusbar

preferredStatusBarStyle .lightContent doesn't work with Navigation Controller. I have tried this method below

```
override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

This is my first time to face this kind of issue. This code works in my Previous apps.

I even change this in my target:
[image: I even change this in my target]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preferred status bar style of view controller is ignored when in navigation controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41026514/preferred-status-bar-style-of-view-controller-is-ignored-when-in-navigation-cont)

Answer (score 2):

I think you forget to change statusbar style in info.plist

Change in **info.plist** the row 
**View controller-based status bar appearance** and set it to **YES**

**and in Your ViewController:**

```
 override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle { return .lightContent }
```

No other code is required

Comment: i have set it to no , seconde I don't want to set it in app delegate if I do that the entire app will be what inside app delegate

Comment: Then set it to YES

Comment: still doesn't work I have navigation controller and its work fine do you think it may be the problem

Comment: `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` add this line in viewDidAppear method of your viewController

Comment: still shows black status bar I already test all these methods but I'm going along with you testing it again nothing works

Comment: my project is empty of any code I'm trying to set this method first

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that in your Info.plist file you have `View controller-based status bar appearance` set to `NO`. It would also be helpful to check that you don't programatically set the status bar to a different color in a view controller by accident. If you're using the above function, do you call `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`? But you shouldn't need to write any code at all if you set `Light` as the value in your project settings and `NO` in your plist file.

Another option that has worked for me in the past is in your AppDelegate file, in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function do this:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent

    return true
}
```

Comment: i have set it to no , seconde I don't want to set it in app delegate if I do that the entire app will be what inside app delegate

Comment: The entire app will not be inside of app delegate – putting the code in app delegate merely makes the code applicable to every file and object in your app.

Comment: it's work but with this code every viewController will be set to light content

Comment: Do you only want specific view controllers to have a light status bar or all of them? If you want specific view controllers, you'll need to set the value in the plist to yes, include the specific code, and then call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate` in the `viewDidLoad` method of each view controller you want to have a light status bar.

Comment: i had do what you just said nothing work, it's maybe an Xcode issue I will delete my app and rebuild it thanks for your time

Comment: the problem was i had a navigation controller try those methods on navigationController and see your self if it's will work or not