# Do Swift extensions take priority over subclasses?

Tags: swift, overriding, subclass, swift-extensions

I'm thinking of defining:

```
extension UIViewController {
  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
  }
}
```

Does this also work for subclasses, like:

```
class UINavigationController: UIViewController {      
  override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return false
  }
}
```

Is the property true or false? Does the extension take priority over the subclass or the other way around?

Comment: From the Swift book on extensions: *“Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality.”*

Comment: Did you try it? What did you find?

Comment: Related: [Overriding methods in Swift extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions)

Comment: The premise of the question is invalid. You can't 'override' the property `prefersStatusBarHidden` in a `UIViewController` extension, because `prefersStatusBarHidden` is a `UIViewController` property, not a superclass property - not to mention that you can't override in extensions. So there's only one way to do it (with a subclass).

Comment: Thanks, @SørenMortensen, you're right. This seems to be different from Objective-C.