# Why does my UITextView not resize when there is a '\n' character

Tags: swift

using this function, whenever I have a '\n' character in the text of my UITextView, it doesn't resize text size properly to fit the specified frame size, but when i remove the '\n' character, it works perfect does anyone know why?

```
extension UITextView{
open override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    var defaultFontSize = CGFloat(44.0)
    self.font = UIFont(name: (self.font?.fontName)!, size: defaultFontSize)
    if (self.contentSize.height > self.frame.size.height) {
        var fontIncrement = CGFloat(1.0)
        while (self.contentSize.height > self.frame.size.height) {
            print(defaultFontSize - fontIncrement)
            self.font = UIFont(name: (self.font?.fontName)!, size: defaultFontSize - fontIncrement)
            fontIncrement += 1.0
        }
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: FYI - extensions can't be used to override methods. They are only to be used to add new methods.

Comment: what do you mean? I am using this so when a uitextview is added to a view the size will adjust accordingly to frame size. Are you implying this won't work, or are you just saying for future reference?

Comment: I'm saying you are attempting to override an existing method with an extension. That's isn't going to work. Swift extensions do not support overriding existing methods. *"Extensions can add new functionality to a type, but they cannot override existing functionality."* - from the [Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH24-ID151) chapter of the Swift book. If you want to override a method, create a subclass.

Comment: so pretty much that if i already have a didmovetosuper method for the uitextview that it won't call this method, but if i don't than it will?Sorry, but I was confused by this because the function works and gets called whenever i add a uitextview to a view.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions