# Override class variable declared in the superclass's extension in Swift

Tags: swift, uicolor

Is it a bug of Swift 5.0.1 or Xcode?

This is in the playground with Xcode 10.2.1.

The codes are:

```swift
extension UIColor {
    @objc class var myGolden: UIColor {
        return self.init(red: 1.000, green: 0.894, blue: 0.541, alpha: 0.900)
    }
}
print(UIColor.myGolden)

class MyUIColor: UIColor {
    override class var myGolden: UIColor {
        return super.init(red: 1.000, green: 0.894, blue: 0.541, alpha: 0.750)
    }
}
print(MyUIColor.myGolden)
```

The playground does not indicate any error for the class `MyUIColor`

The output is:

```
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 1 0.894 0.541 0.9
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

and the runtime error says:

> error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT. The process
>   has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread
>   return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.

Comment: Full error message (that could be usefull) tested in iOS Simulator: "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[iOSTest.MyUIColor initWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x..."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding methods in Swift extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions)

Comment: @holex: Unless I am mistaken, this is *not* the same issue. Here the property is overridden in a subclass, not in the extension.

Comment: Even though my answer solve the runtime error, it's not really clear why your code doesn't work. Inside of a class function/computed property, `self` and `super` should refer to the type of the class/struct, so in your case `self.init` and `super.init` should be equivalent to `UIColor.init`. Moreover, trying out an equivalent code but using only pure Swift classes, it all works fine. I think you've probably found an error in the Swift/Objective-C bridging.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `self.init` and `super.init` calls to `UIColor.init` fixes the issue. You should only call `self.init` and `super.init` from convenience initialisers or subclass initialisers respectively, when creating an instance of your class in a computed property or any other functions, you should be calling the init methods using the type name rather than `self` or `super`.

```
extension UIColor {
    @objc class var myGolden: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 0.894, blue: 0.541, alpha: 0.9)
    }
}
print(UIColor.myGolden)

class MyUIColor: UIColor {
    override class var myGolden: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 0.894, blue: 0.541, alpha: 0.75)
    }
}
print(MyUIColor.myGolden)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the class variable override, is instead the improper use of `self.init` and `super.init`. You should change the code as follows:

```
extension UIColor {
    @objc class var myGolden: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 0.894, blue: 0.541, alpha: 0.900)
    }
}
print(UIColor.myGolden)

class MyUIColor: UIColor {
    override class var myGolden: UIColor {
        return UIColor(red: 1.000, green: 0.894, blue: 0.541, alpha: 0.750)
    }
}
print(MyUIColor.myGolden)
```