# Extension vs Class in UITests helper class

Tags: class, static, extension-methods, helper, xcuitest

I want to write helper class for my UI tests.

*A.swift (Test cases class)*

```
class A:XCTestCase {
//contains test cases, setUp() & tearDown()
...
}
```

*B.swift (Helper class)*

**Method 1:**

```
class B:XCTestCase {
//only helper functions, no setUp, no tearDown and no test cases

func sampleHelper() {
 ...
}
...
}
```

`B().sampleHelper()` will call the sampleHelper function (when used within **A**)

**Method 2:**

```
extension XCTestCase {
//only helper functions, no setUp, no tearDown and no test cases
func sampleHelper() {
 ...
}
...
}
```

`sampleHelper()` will call the helper function (when used within **A**)

**Question:**

Which is the optimal method in writing helper classes? I know extension is static but does it really affect the memory/performance if the code base is huge?

Comment: I always use the second method. This is less verbose than the first method and makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add **only** some custom methods to XCTestCase it is better and more clear to use **method #2** and place the whole extension to separate file/folder somewhere near the place you want to use your custom methods

On the other hand, you should not use **method #2** if you want to override methods of XCTestCase as it is violation of the language directive. More details you can read in [Apple Developer Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html) and in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions).