# Apple way in Swift instead of an override?

Tags: swift

what approach does Apple use in Swift instead of override, how can I write this without using the @objc marker

```
import Foundation

class A {
    init() {}
}
extension A {
    @objc func foo() {
        print("foo")
    }
}

class B: A {
    override func foo() {
        print("yes2")
    }
}

A().foo()
B().foo()
```

maybe protocols? but how?

Comment: This is not possible in pure Swift by design. Also duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274660

Comment: Your question is unclear. You don't need either `override` or `@objc` for `extension` methods.

Comment: The Swift language does not support overriding methods in extensions (unless with the @objc, but that is a kludge).  You could possibly achieve what you wanted by taking a compositional approach; using a protocol to define the method,  a default implementation in a protocol extension as the "standard" method, and then implementing local method in those classes that needed something different.  How practical this is would depend on what you're looking to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a protocol and provide a default method implementation. Then all you need is to comform to that protocol and provide its own foo method if necessary:

```
protocol Fooable {
    func foo()
}
```

---

```
extension Fooable {
    func foo() {
        print("default implementation")
    }
}
```

---

```
class A: Fooable { }

class B: A {
    func foo() {
        print("B implementationn")
    }
}
```

---

```
let a = A()
let b = B()

a.foo()
b.foo()
```

---

This will print

> default implementation
>
> B implementationn