# Swift defined convenience init is not accessible in objective-c

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, nsobject

I have a swift class which is a subclass of `NSObject`. The problem is when I try to define init in an extension. Consider this sample class:

```
public class Person: NSObject {
  public init(name: String) {
    self.name = name 
  }
}
```

So when I define init in an extension like this in my main app:

```
extension Person {
  @objc public convenience override init() {
    self.init(name: "test")
  }
}
```

and try to create object in objective-c like this:

```
[[Person alloc] init];
```

it gives me this error: `'init' is unavailable` and it forces me to use `initWithName`

but when I define init inside the class and not extension, everything works:

```
public class Person: NSObject {
  public init(name: String) {
    self.name = name 
  }

  @objc public convenience override init() {
    self.init(name: "test")
  }
}
```

I'm sure the extension is available to my obj-c class and also have imported "ProjectTarget-Swift.h" to my obj-c file but have no idea why this doesn't work, anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: Might be related to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213286/overriding-methods-in-swift-extensions. The initializer is still a method in Objective-C.

Comment: @Cristik thanks for pointing this out, it makes sense, because if I create other convenience inits in extension it works, it only doesn't allow `override init` :(